# How to load local *.htm file to WPF WebBroswer with relative path

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load local HTML file in a C# WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194851/load-local-html-file-in-a-c-sharp-webbrowser)

I´m creating program in C# (VS 2010), and I´d like to show help file. I created file help.htm. This file is included to solution in help directory.
And I´d like this htm file load to webBroswer in Dialog. But there is a probelm, when I try to use relative path.

```
            HelpWindow helpwin = new HelpWindow(); //creating new window

            Uri helpUri = new Uri ("help\\pm_view.htm",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); //setting path

            helpwin.webBrowser.Navigate(helpUri); //navigating webBroswer
```

After that, i get error: Relative URIs are not allowed. Parameter name: source

There is my C# solution schema in picture:

[image]

Please can anyone help?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not the question but did you consider a FlowDocument?  They display nicely in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using

> Path.GetFullPath(YourRelativePath)

as per this answer: [Answer on relative paths in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3342049/169334)?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a short article about this: [WebBrowserEx: WinForms WebBrowser + HTTP Server](http://simplygenius.net/Article/WebBrowserEx)

The code is for WinForms, but you could modify it for WPF.