# How to specify path to Image resources in WPF application

Tags: wpf, image, resources, embedded-resource, relative-path

Below is in a flow document
I can see all 5 in design
When I run the program then none are found
How can I get relative path to work?

```
<Paragraph>
    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="zHelpMain.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="Images\VennIntersection.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="/Gabe2a;component/Images/VennUnion.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="/Images/helpMain.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>
    <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="images\helpMain.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Paragraph>
```

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444699/wpf-relative-image-source-path ?

Comment: How do you store image files in the assembly?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I just have them in those locations in my project.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Blam, are they defined as resources in your project? (check the "Build action" property)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The problem is that the files do not have a build action property.  I will try and post an image.

Comment: @Blam, files in a project always have a build action... are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque See image I add to question. I don't know what I did to mess stuff up.  I have an image I add to the project a long time ago that does have build property.

Comment: Your images doesn't belong to any project. You must add them to project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the image files are part of the solution, but not part of the project, so they're not embedded in the assembly when you compile. You need to add the to the Gabe2a project, with the build action set to "Resource".

Comment: How do I add them to the project?  I have tried add existing item and they end up in that Solution Items.  And not build option.

Comment: OK I finally figured it out.  Your words were clear enough.  I was blinded by the light.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1). You have to add all Image files to your WPF project, for example, place them in **Img** directory; by default `Build Action` will be set to '**Resources**'. Keep it intact.

2). Specify path to the image like:

```
Source="/[assembly name];component/Img/ImageFile
```

Pertinent to your particular case, the following syntax looks OK:

```
Source="/Gabe2a;component/Images/VennUnion.png"
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,